# How to enable “UI check” in android studio iguana

Tags: android, android-studio

I have seen that they have released a new way to check all the devices for the UI issues but I'm unable to see it I'm using the iguana android studio? Can someone please tell me the steps to view that.

[image: Like the one in this]

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/testing#compose-ui-check)?

Comment: Yes. @tomerpacific. it was unclear I thought it was somewhere else. found it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out. hovering over the preview you will see the option to start the UI check mode.